# Microsoft Surfacebook use USB as display port

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, external-display, microsoft-surface

I own a Microsoft Surfacebook 1, and my USB 3.0 is not registered my external monitor. My miniDisplayPort is already hooked up to another monitor, and I would like to avoid paying $100 for a display port.

Could there be an option to download a driver to be able to use the USB 3.0 as an external display port?

Please let me know if this is possible. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot use a USB 3.0 as a display port.

Answer (score 1):

By itself, a standard USB Type-A host port has no means to drive DisplayPort directly. If the port is of Type-C, there could be an option to do DP, but it needs to be designed in, which is not always true. To use the standard USB 3.0 port to drive a display, you need to purchase a USB 3.0 to DisplayPort adapter, [like this one](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158339),

[image]

These devices use a serious IC to bridge from USB3 to DisplayPort following USB Video class specifications. This is a USB device that provides one or more monitors to a system. Most common maker of these bridges is [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/)

Comment: It might be noteworthy that these adapters don’t have any kind of hardware accelerated 3D or whatever. They’re only suitable for office applications and web surfing.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I have a better understanding DP